# Built-in or recommended way to retry chain of async operations in RxJava

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java

I have a graph of inter-dependent asynchronous operations modeled in RxJava. For some
errors, the entire graph should be re-run. The `retry(..)`
operators do not support this directly because any error is presented to all subscribers. Since the `retry(..)` operators just re-subscribe, they always get the error, computed only once, from the final observable. i.e. the work is not performed again on re-subscribe.

I have tried creating a special observable that invokes an observable-producing
method for every subscription. In that case, the retry operators do work
mostly as desired and after some additional cache operation, work exactly
as desired.

However, this seems like it would be so common that I suspect I am repeating
work already provided somewhere in RxJava. I am also concerned about the
robustness of my solution given that I am trying to do something at a low
level possibly without enough RxJava knowledge to do so. The other problem
is composability: to support all three `retry(..)` forms, I would need three versions of
the wrapper method.

The demonstration below explains what I am trying to do and the success so far.

Is there a simpler or more idiomatic (or both) way to do this kind of retry in RxJava?

```
package demo;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observable.OnSubscribe;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.functions.Func0;
import rx.util.async.Async;

/**
 ** <p>
 * Demonstrate attempts to get RxJava retry for asynchronous work chain. The use
 * case that exposed this problem is reading and writing data with versioning
 * for optimistic concurrency. The work is a series of async I/O operations that
 * must be re-assembled from scratch if a stale version is detected on write.
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * Four cases are demonstrated in this class:
 * </p>
 * <ul>
 * <li>Case 1: perform the work and naiively apply a retry operator to the
 * asynchronous work. This fails because the work itself is not retried on
 * re-subscribe.</li>
 * <li>Case 2: wrap the work in an observer that performs it on every
 * subscription. A retry operator applied to the wrapper correctly re-attempts
 * the work on failure. However, every subsequent subscriber to the result
 * causes the work to be performed again.</li>
 * <li>Case 3: Apply the cache operator to the result of the retry operator.
 * This performs as desired.</li>
 * <li>Case 4: Generalize the approach of case 3 and encapsulate it in an
 * observable generator method. This shows that it is difficult to generalize
 * this behavior because each retry operator form (number, predicate, perpetual)
 * will require its own generator method.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>
 * NOTE: this code does not work if compiled by the Eclipse (Keppler) compiler
 * for Java 8. I have to compile with javac for it to work. There is some
 * problem with Lambda class naming in the code generated by Eclipse.
 * </p>
 *
 *
 */
public class AsyncRetryDemo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        new AsyncRetryDemo().case1();
        new AsyncRetryDemo().case2();
        new AsyncRetryDemo().case3();
        new AsyncRetryDemo().case4();

        // output is:
        //
        // case 1, sub 1: fail (max retries, called=1)
        // case 1, sub 2: fail (max retries, called=1)
        // case 2, sub 1: pass (called=2)
        // case 2, sub 2: fail (called=3)
        // case 3, sub 1: pass (called=2)
        // case 3, sub 2: pass (called=2)
        // case 4, sub 1: pass (called=2)
        // case 4, sub 2: pass (called=2)

    }

    private final AtomicInteger called = new AtomicInteger();

    private final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(2);

    /**
     * This represents a sequence of interdependent asynchronous operations that
     * might fail in a way that prescribes a retry (but in this case, all we are
     * doing is squaring an integer asynchronously and failing the first time).
     *
     * @param input
     *            to the process.
     *
     * @return promise to perform the work and produce either a result or a
     *         suggestion to retry (e.g. a stale version error).
     */
    private Observable<Integer> canBeRetried(final int a) {

        final Observable<Integer> rval;
        if (this.called.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
            rval = Observable.error(new RuntimeException(
                    "we always fail the first time"));
        } else {
            rval = Async.start(() -> a * a);
        }

        return rval;

    }

    private void case1() throws InterruptedException {

        /*
         * In this case, we invoke the observable-creator to get the async
         * promise. Of course, if it fails, any retry will fail as well because
         * the failed result is computed one time and pushed to all subscribers
         * forever.
         *
         * Thus this case fails because the first invocation of canBeRetried(..)
         * always fails.
         */
        final Observable<Integer> o = canBeRetried(2)

                .retry(2);

        check("case 1", o);

        this.done.await();

    }

    private void case2() throws InterruptedException {

        /*
         * In this case, we wrap canBeRetried(..) inside an observer that
         * invokes it on every subscription. So, we get past the retry problem.
         * But every new subscriber after the retry succeeds causes the work to
         * restart.
         */
        final Observable<Integer> o = Observable.create(
                new OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(final Subscriber<? super Integer> child) {
                        canBeRetried(2).subscribe(child);
                    }
                })

                .retry(2);

        check("case 2", o);

        this.done.await();

    }

    private void case3() throws InterruptedException {

        /*
         * In this case, we wrap canBeRetried(..) inside an observer that
         * invokes it on every subscription. So, we get past the retry problem.
         * We cache the result of the retry to solve the extra work problem.
         */
        final Observable<Integer> o = Observable.create(
                new OnSubscribe<Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(final Subscriber<? super Integer> child) {
                        canBeRetried(2).subscribe(child);
                    }
                })
                .retry(2)

                .cache();

        check("case 3", o);

        this.done.await();

    }

    private void case4() throws InterruptedException {

        /*
         * Same as case 3 but we use the retryAndCache(..) to do the work for
         * us.
         */
        final Observable<Integer> o = retryAndCache(() -> canBeRetried(2), 2);

        check("case 4", o);

        this.done.await();

    }

    private void check(final String label, final Observable<Integer> promise) {

        // does the work get retried on failure?
        promise.subscribe(
                v -> {
                    System.out.println(label + ", sub 1: "
                            + (this.called.get() == 2 ? "pass" : "fail")
                            + " (called=" + this.called.get() + ")");
                },
                x -> {
                    System.out.println(label
                            + ", sub 1: fail (max retries, called="
                            + this.called.get() + ")");
                    this.done.countDown();
                }, () -> {
                    this.done.countDown();
                });

        // do subsequent subscribers avoid invoking the work again?
        promise.subscribe(
                v -> {
                    System.out.println(label + ", sub 2: "
                            + (this.called.get() == 2 ? "pass" : "fail")
                            + " (called=" + this.called.get() + ")");
                },
                x -> {
                    System.out.println(label
                            + ", sub 2: fail (max retries, called="
                            + this.called.get() + ")");
                    this.done.countDown();
                }, () -> {
                    this.done.countDown();
                });

    }

    /**
     * Generalized retry and cache for case 4.
     *
     * @param binder
     *            user-provided supplier that assembles and starts the
     *            asynchronous work.
     *
     * @param retries
     *            number of times to retry on error.
     *
     * @return promise to perform the work and retry up to retry times on error.
     */
    private static <R> Observable<R> retryAndCache(
            final Func0<Observable<R>> binder, final int retries) {

        return Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<R>() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super R> child) {
                binder.call().subscribe(child);
            }
        })

        .retry(retries)

        .cache();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your problem statement. Are you wanting to repeat all work from various observables on an error, or only some of the work?

Comment: In this case `#canBeRetried(..)` encapsulates the arbitrary work that must be restarted from scratch if retried. This work could be part of a larger composition.  The driving case for this problem was optimistic update to a database where the work is: _read_ -> _compute change_ -> _write_.  If _write_ fails due to a stale version, the retry must start again with the _read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have a few options to do it better.

First option is to use [defer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html) instead of create :

```
private void case5() throws InterruptedException {
    // Same as case 3 but using defer
    final Observable<Integer> o = Observable.defer(() -> canBeRetried(2)).retry(2).cache();

    check("case 5", o);

    this.done.await();
}
```

However the real problem is with canBeRetired method; it must be called on each retry. 
The better approach is to create an Observable which re-execute logic for each subscription. The method might look like:

```
 private Observable<Integer> canBeRetriedBetter(final int a) {
    return Observable.defer(() -> canBeRetried(a));
}
```

And the code:

```
private void case6() throws InterruptedException {

    final Observable<Integer> o = canBeRetriedBetter(2).retry(2).cache();

    check("case 6", o);

    this.done.await();
}
```

Further improvements can be gain using [compose](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#compose(rx.Observable.Transformer)) and custom transformation. Using them, you can apply a set of commonly used operators to any chain in a consistent, reusable manner.

For example we may define operator which calls cache and retry on a stream:

```
   public static class RetryAndCache<T> implements Observable.Transformer<T, T>{
    private final int count;
    public RetryAndCache(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> o) {
        return o.retry(count).cache();
    }
}
```

And finally, the code:

```
private void case7() throws InterruptedException {

    final Observable<Integer> o = canBeRetriedBetter(2).compose(new RetryAndCache(2));

    check("case 7", o);

    this.done.await();
}
```

Comment: Nice. Especially like your insight resulting in defer with a supplier.